# problem with DWR integration in spring?

Tags: xml, namespaces, spring, dwr

Actually this is not, how can we integrate DWR and all that. But actually the problem is i am using

```
xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
```

and few hours back *'http://www.directwebremoting.org'* was down, so i was unable to deploy my application, And now when the site is back i got to know that this link *'http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr'* doesn't exist any more.

So what could be the possible resolution of this problem, Why do it connects to the specified site.  And what should i do so that even if the site is down, or the link is not available, my application should be still deployable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they may have moved the location of the xsd on DWR's site.  You should be able to fix this by addiing the `schemaLocation` to your config file like so:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">
```

If you are concerned about the availability of DWR's site you could either put the schema on a location available to your local network or reference it using the `file:` syntax to reference something on your local machine.  I'm not sure if there's a way you can reference the schema on the classpath though.